# Custom credential not working in Windows 10 Virtual Box VM

Tags: windows, windows-10, winlogon, credential-providers

I downloaded the windows evaluation VM from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/, to test my custom credential provider.

The same credential provider works with physical machines, for both LogonUI and CredUI cases. While the one installed in the VM, works only in the CredUI case. During the LogonUI case, the CP is not even called (Verified using log file).

Are there any registry settings that should be tuned?

Comment: Does your VM 32 or 64-bit? 
Do you compile and register both credential provider versions 32 and 64-bit in case of 64-bit OS?

Comment: The VM is 64-Bit and cred provider is also 64-Bit.

Comment: Try to disable all of credential provider filters.

Comment: There is only one Generic CredProvider Filter.

Comment: Try to disable it. Also you can check that your VM is non in recovery or safe boot mode.

Comment: Check out this [page](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/force-windows-to-boot-into-safe-mode-without-using-the-f8-key/)

Comment: Unable to disable the default Cred provider filter. And on the boot mode. Its normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182247/discussion-between-alexander-and-buzz-lightyear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credential provider I was developing is a .NET interop dll. The dll needs to be signed with a strong name. I registered the dll after signing and was able to view the CP in the Logon UI

Comment: Does this have something to see with the fact credential providers are COM-based components ?

Comment: I think it is more related to COM and .Net interaction. Credential Provider is one of examples / victims.